# Angular run type checks manually

Tags: angular, typescript, continuous-integration, angular-cli, typechecking

I'm trying to setup a pipeline which would lint and test my Angular app befor build and deploy. It turns out that `ng lint` doesn't run type checking which happens at build time for AOT.

Is there a way to run these checks manually using Angular CLI? So that I would get template errors in pre-commit hook before they occur during build.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "angularCompilerOptions" in the tsconfig.json for such things.
For example:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "no-unused-variable": true,
    "no-unused-imports": true,
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "preserveWhitespaces": false
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This affects build time. I've already my config set up.  I need to run checks for these errors BEFORE I build an app

Comment: how about adding to you compiler options the following: "noEmitHelpers": true, "importHelpers": true, "noUnusedLocals": true,

Comment: Why would I do this